# How to have a datasource configuration as external Jar in spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, datasource

I want to create a spring boot JAR(standalone) which contains Java data source configuration and I want to utilize that JAR in other micro services for connecting to DB (instead of giving credentials in each application.properties file). I have succeeded in creating the JAR with java data source configuration. But when I add that jar to any service, the service is still expecting me to provide credentials in application.properties.

Could anyone help on how to have data source configuration in an external JAR and use that jar in service for db connection

Answer (score 0):

You could implement a single properties file to take the data source credentials from there (you don't necessarily have to use Spring Boot's default application.properties) and then the easiest way to get the connection is by defining a DataSource factory method and placing it inside a class annotated with the @Configuration annotation:

```
@Configuration
public class DataSourceConfig {
    
    @Bean
    public DataSource getDataSource() {
        DataSourceBuilder dataSourceBuilder = DataSourceBuilder.create();
        dataSourceBuilder.driverClassName("org.h2.Driver");
        dataSourceBuilder.url("jdbc:h2:mem:test");
        dataSourceBuilder.username("SA");
        dataSourceBuilder.password("");
        return dataSourceBuilder.build();
    }
}
```

This manually generates the connection to the data source that you are indicating, just make sure that all the necessary libraries for the connection are being imported correctly in your pom.xml file if you are using Maven.

Comment: Thanks Fernando for your suggestion. In my case, data source for this app is working fine. My requirement is to import this app as a dependency in other projects instead of defining data source in each project. When I import this app (as JAR) in my other jpa project, the project is still forcing me to add data source separately instead of utilizing this (from the JAR i added as dependency ). So, please let me know if there is any way to import this JAR in multiple projects to utilize data source config from this JAR

Comment: @user3286888 did you find any solution for this.